# ms access graphic load on subform

Tags: ms-access, subform

here i have a question about ms access graphic.

i need to display a graphic (subform), when i give 2 parameters on a form.
i wrote the control between in my query wizard, to control the display of the graphic, n it work great.

On the form where i need the graphic display, i give it textbox and a command button to executing the loaded subform. My question is what the event procedure should i give to the command button so the graphic will load below it text?
please anyone would solve my problems?
thankyou very much
i give it screenshot of my database
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhcNk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Include these parameters in an SQL statement that is the RowSource for the graph. Show the query statement that is your graph's RowSource if you need help with building that statement.

Why do you need a subform? Why not graph on the main form?

The button doesn't need to 'load' the graph, just needs to refresh the form with code in button Click event: `Me.Refresh`.